# The number of lambda outer subquery iteration variable evaluations

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda, max

From the [LINQ Quiz](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqquiz.aspx) questions and answers to Q4 and Q5

With `colors` array defined as:

```
string[] colors = { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" };
```

and query from Answer to Q4:

```
var query =
  from c in colors
  where c.Length == colors.Max (c2 => c2.Length)
  select c;
```

Do I understand correctly that the outer query iteration expression `c2.Length` will be evaluated 16 times?

that is, for each item `с` in `colors` array, the `colors.Max (c2 => c2.Length)` will be evaluated once, i.e. `Max()` calculation will be done 4 times i total. And for each `Max()` evaluation the `c2.Length` will be found 4 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's correct.  Easy to check as well, if you have LINQPad try:

```
string[] colors = { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" };

int count = 0;

var query =
    from c in colors
    where c.Length == colors.Max (c2 => 
        {
            count.Dump();
            count++;
            return c2.Length;
        }
    )
    select c;

query.Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer lacks the info that is necessary to choose "C# Statement(s)" from "Language" dropdown listbox in LinqPad in order to run it there. I'd rather prefer sticking with regular console app than studying additional tools